# Possible to build Telegram client with Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, telegram, tdlib

I'd like to use Tdlib to make a Telegram client with Ionic ie build to web, iOS, and Android.

I've got tdlib running locally but's unclear how tdlib will be included in a compiled Ionic app or if it's possible without writing a cordova plugin.

Are there any examples of this somewhere?